# Spring Boot directly throws "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread" after starting the application

Tags: java, spring-boot, out-of-memory, threadpoolexecutor

I am running a SpringBoot-Application on my Strato V-Server (https://www.strato.de/server/linux-vserver/ => V-Server Linux V10 with 8GB RAM).
Whenn I start the Application I directly get the error mentioned in the Title.
I have two task executors:

```
@Configuration
public class AsynchronousSpringEventsConfig {
    @Bean(name = "applicationEventMulticaster")
    public ApplicationEventMulticaster simpleApplicationEventMulticaster() {
        SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster eventMulticaster =
                new SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster();
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor
                = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix(
                "AsyncThreadPoolTaskExecutor");
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(25);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        eventMulticaster.setTaskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor);
        return eventMulticaster;
    }
}
```

and:

```
    @Bean(name = "gaxThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor
                = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix(
                "MainThreadPoolTaskExecutor");
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
```

when I remove the CorePoolSize and the MaxPoolSize from both everthings running fine. But I originally wanted to have the MaxPoolSize for the first one set to 100 and for the second as it is above.

Has somebody an idea how to fix it? Do you need more Information?

**EDIT**

I am running the following java version on the server:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~18.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)
```

and the following command I use to start the spring application:

```
/usr/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=6006 -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -jar gaxify.jar
```

The Log/Stacktrace when the error occurs:

```
2021-01-03 13:48:17,959 INFO org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger [main] Starting Application v1.0-SNAPSHOT on stratoserver.net with PID 4828 (/home/gaxify/gaxify.jar started by root in /home/gaxify)
2021-01-03 13:48:18,016 INFO org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication [main] No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-01-03 13:48:19,827 INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate [main] Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-01-03 13:48:20,020 INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate [main] Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 179ms. Found 9 repository interfaces.
2021-01-03 13:48:20,796 INFO org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker [main] Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-01-03 13:48:20,862 INFO org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport [main] Initializing ExecutorService
2021-01-03 13:48:21,411 INFO org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [main] Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-01-03 13:48:21,428 INFO org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [main] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2021-01-03 13:48:21,429 INFO org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [main] Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-01-03 13:48:21,430 INFO org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [main] Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2021-01-03 13:48:21,531 INFO org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [main] Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-01-03 13:48:21,532 INFO org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext [main] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3411 ms
2021-01-03 13:48:21,955 INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [main] HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-01-03 13:48:22,252 INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [main] HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-01-03 13:48:23,224 INFO liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger [main] SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangeloglock
2021-01-03 13:48:23,226 INFO liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger [main] SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangeloglock
2021-01-03 13:48:23,228 INFO liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger [main] SELECT LOCKED FROM public.databasechangeloglock WHERE ID=1
2021-01-03 13:48:23,244 INFO liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger [main] Changelog-Protokoll erfolgreich gesperrt.
2021-01-03 13:48:24,449 INFO liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger [main] SELECT MD5SUM FROM public.databasechangelog WHERE MD5SUM IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1
2021-01-03 13:48:24,452 INFO liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger [main] SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangelog
2021-01-03 13:48:24,453 INFO liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger [main] Reading from public.databasechangelog
2021-01-03 13:48:24,454 INFO liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger [main] SELECT * FROM public.databasechangelog ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
2021-01-03 13:48:24,547 INFO liquibase.logging.core.Slf4jLogger [main] Successfully released change log lock
2021-01-03 13:48:24,549 INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [main] HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-01-03 13:48:24,583 INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [main] HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-01-03 13:48:24,653 INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [main] HikariPool-2 - Starting...
2021-01-03 13:48:24,695 INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [main] HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
2021-01-03 13:48:24,746 INFO org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [main] HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-01-03 13:48:24,849 INFO org.hibernate.Version [main] HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.6.Final}
2021-01-03 13:48:25,141 INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager [main] HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2021-01-03 13:48:25,337 INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect [main] HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
2021-01-03 13:48:26,032 WARN org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator [main] HHH000409: Using org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator which does not generate IETF RFC 4122 compliant UUID values; consider using org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator instead
2021-01-03 13:48:27,306 INFO org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator [main] HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-01-03 13:48:27,317 INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean [main] Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-01-03 13:48:28,158 INFO org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport [main] Initializing ExecutorService 'gaxThreadPoolTaskExecutor'
2021-01-03 13:48:28,324 INFO org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport [main] Initializing ExecutorService 'threadPoolTaskScheduler'
2021-01-03 13:48:28,411 WARN org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration [main] spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-01-03 13:48:28,485 INFO de.gaxify.backend.task.StartGaxTask [MainThreadPoolTaskExecutor1] ########## Schedule Token Task
2021-01-03 13:48:28,486 INFO org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport [MainThreadPoolTaskExecutor1] Initializing ExecutorService
2021-01-03 13:48:28,498 INFO de.gaxify.backend.task.StartGaxTask [MainThreadPoolTaskExecutor1] ########## Schedule CSV Task
2021-01-03 13:48:28,498 INFO org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport [MainThreadPoolTaskExecutor1] Initializing ExecutorService
2021-01-03 13:48:28,499 INFO de.gaxify.backend.rest.token.TokenTask [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1] #############running token task
2021-01-03 13:48:28,507 INFO de.gaxify.backend.task.StartGaxTask [MainThreadPoolTaskExecutor1] ########## Schedule Trade Task
2021-01-03 13:48:28,507 INFO org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport [MainThreadPoolTaskExecutor1] Initializing ExecutorService
2021-01-03 13:48:28,521 INFO de.gaxify.backend.task.StartGaxTask [MainThreadPoolTaskExecutor1] ########## Schedule Report Task
2021-01-03 13:48:28,522 INFO org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport [MainThreadPoolTaskExecutor1] Initializing ExecutorService
2021-01-03 13:48:29,636 INFO de.gaxify.backend.rest.token.TokenTask [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1] Token for Company 'Schuhhaus Fischer' is 'bearer 88991645-28a0-4d56-a671-a611fa073f9f'
2021-01-03 13:48:29,984 INFO org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain [main] Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@289778cd, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4f824872, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@26f7cdf8, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6c03fb16, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@50acf55d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@61f80d55, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@363f0ba0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@7495699f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@11e33bac, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@29629fbb, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@35dd9ed3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7c2312fa, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@23202c31, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3e7545e8, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6401d0a0]
2021-01-03 13:48:30,044 INFO org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointLinksResolver [main] Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2021-01-03 13:48:30,112 INFO org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [main] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2021-01-03 13:48:30,158 INFO org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [main] Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-01-03 13:48:30,161 INFO org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger [main] Started Application in 13.24 seconds (JVM running for 14.0)
2021-01-03 13:48:30,180 ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication [main] Application run failed
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1367)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:314)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.running(EventPublishingRunListener.java:103)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.running(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:77)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at de.gaxify.Application.main(Application.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
2021-01-03 13:48:30,182 WARN org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext [main] Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1367)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:314)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:978)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:803)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at de.gaxify.Application.main(Application.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
2021-01-03 13:48:30,187 INFO org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport [main] Shutting down ExecutorService 'threadPoolTaskScheduler'
2021-01-03 13:48:30,187 INFO org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport [main] Shutting down ExecutorService 'gaxThreadPoolTaskExecutor'
2021-01-03 13:48:30,190 INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean [main] Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-01-03 13:48:30,202 INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [main] HikariPool-2 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-01-03 13:48:30,237 INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [main] HikariPool-2 - Shutdown completed.
2021-01-03 13:48:30,240 INFO org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [main] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2021-01-03 13:48:30,246 INFO org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [main] Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-01-03 13:48:30,251 INFO org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [main] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2021-01-03 13:48:30,279 INFO org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [main] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2021-01-03 13:48:32,980 INFO de.gaxify.backend.trade.TradeTask [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1] Trade status for Company 'Schuhhaus Fischer': 200
2021-01-03 13:48:33,041 ERROR org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1] Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.liquibase-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties': Could not bind properties to 'LiquibaseProperties' : prefix=spring.liquibase, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@10bdf5e5 has been closed already
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolvePreparedArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:821)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:151)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:617)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:378)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy161.getTradeByOrderId(Unknown Source)
    at de.gaxify.backend.database.services.GaxifyTradeService.getTradeByOrderId(GaxifyTradeService.java:48)
    at de.gaxify.backend.trade.TradeProcessor.processTrades(TradeProcessor.java:52)
    at de.gaxify.backend.trade.TradeTask.processTrade(TradeTask.java:62)
    at de.gaxify.backend.trade.TradeTask.run(TradeTask.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@10bdf5e5 has been closed already
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1092)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanProvider(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1137)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.getBindHandlerAdvisors(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.getBindHandler(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:107)
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Add information about the used JRE on the server, how are you running the app on the server (command), did you specify any JVM arguments for initial memory configuration (Xms, Xmx) ?

Comment: I added the Information above @Elgayed

Comment: Also, it will be useful to see the first few lines of the stack trace, so that we can see which class is throwing the exception.

Comment: Added the log/stacktrace above @SreeKumar

Comment: Try setting corePoolSize to a smaller value. Remove xms and xmx.

Comment: Set the corePoolSize for both to 2 and removed the xms and xmx it started now thanks:) Hopefully it doesn't run in the same issue overtime when the application is running multiple weeks/month non stop

Comment: @Nimal Did you have any issues after this fix?

Comment: @theprogrammer no after that everthing worked fine. But I have declared a specific Executor i think.